# Tacit function to multiply five consecutive number in a list: J, j701

Tags: loops, j, tacit-programming

I'm working on Project Euler, I'm on [problem 8](http://projecteuler.net/problem=8), and I'm trying a simple brute force: Multiply each consecutive 5 digit of the number, make a list with the results, and find the higher.

This is the code I'm currently trying to write in J:

```
   n =: 731671765313x
   NB. 'n' will be the complete 1000-digits number

   itl =: (".@;"0@":)
   NB. 'itl' transform an integer in a list of his digit

   N =: itl n
   NB. just for short writing

   takeFive =: 5 {. ] }.~ 1 -~ [
   NB. this is a dyad, I get this code thanks to '13 : '5{.(x-1)}.y'
   NB. that take a starting index and it's applied to a list
```

How I can use takeFive for all the index of N?
I tried:

```
  (i.#N) takeFive N
|length error: takeFive
|   (i.#N)    takeFive N
```

but it doesn't work and I don't know why.
Thank you all.

Comment: Just a minor note: your `itl` could be replaced with a simple use of the inverse of Base (#.) `N =: 10 #.inv n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1.* The reason that `(i.#N) takeFive N` is not working is that you are essentially trying to run `5{. ((i.#N)-1) }. N`but you have to use `x` not as a list but as an atom. You can do that by setting the appropriate [left-right rank `"`](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/d600n.htm) of the verb:

```
 (i.#N) (takeFive"0 _) N
7 3 1 6 7
7 3 1 6 7
3 1 6 7 1
1 6 7 1 7
6 7 1 7 6
7 1 7 6 5
1 7 6 5 3
7 6 5 3 1
6 5 3 1 3
5 3 1 3 0
3 1 3 0 0
1 3 0 0 0
```

*2.* One other way is to bind (`&`) your list (`N`) to `takeFive` and then run the binded-verb through every `i.#N`. To do this, it's better to use the reverse version of takeFive: `takeFive~`:

```
((N&(takeFive~))"0) i.#N
7 3 1 6 7
7 3 1 6 7
3 1 6 7 1
1 6 7 1 7
6 7 1 7 6
7 1 7 6 5
1 7 6 5 3
7 6 5 3 1
6 5 3 1 3
5 3 1 3 0
3 1 3 0 0
1 3 0 0 0
```

or `(N&(takeFive~)) each i.#N`.

*3.* I think, though, that the [infix dyad `\`](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/d430.htm) might serve you better:

```
5 >\N
7 3 1 6 7
3 1 6 7 1
1 6 7 1 7
6 7 1 7 6
7 1 7 6 5
1 7 6 5 3
7 6 5 3 1
6 5 3 1 3
```

Comment: Infix dyad is perfect! Thank you! :D